Is there a name or standard for the YAML format used to describe kubernetes resources?
I'm a big Kubernetes / GitOps fan and I'm pretty used to the YAML format to describe a Kubernetes object (manifests).
The concept:
apiVersion: apps/v1  # A reference to some known schema
kind: Deployment  # A subpart of the schema
metadata:
  name: some-name
  description: The keys under metadata also adhere to some schema, at least in Kubernetes manifests
  annotations:
    some-key: some-value
spec:
  key1: this whole object will adhere to the scheme referenced by apiVersion and kind (line 1 and 2)
  key2: the file is invalid if it's not

Sometimes I see the format being used in other places/contexts.
See for example the backstage content description. A different context that is not related to Kubernetes resources. And obviously, it's a nice and recognizable way to have some typing in your YAML files.
Is there a name for this concept or someplace where it is being described more formally? I remember reading that this was some internal standard from Google long before Kubernetes.
Found 'names' so far:

Descriptor format (backstage specific?)
Kubernetes object format


I'd probably call this a "Kubernetes manifest file" like in your linked documentation, even if the apiVersion: isn't a Kubernetes API at all.

Thanks @DavidMaze,  I'm really looking for a name of the format itself. A manifest file would also point at the contents. But perhaps Im just being to curious.

These yaml format files will be called by different names based on which tool these are being used like in kubernetes some might call these as kubernetes definition files, In Ansible these are called playbooks. Similarly there are a lot of names for this kind of yaml format.

@DharaniDharGolladasari Ansible playbooks don't have apiVersion, kind, metadata, spec etc fields within yaml

Finnaly found it! The original Kubernetes lead architect wrote a recent article about this: https://itnext.io/on-using-the-kubernetes-resource-model-for-declarative-configuration-a5dd11b99546
The short answer: he called it a KRM Spec. But the whole background in why it's so similar to the API design makes this so powerful and interesting.
